# Measure Line while editing in Edit Mode (Workaround?)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, editing, tools, measurements

It's unfortunate that QGIS does not allow the use of the Measure Line tool while activiely editing something with *Add feature* or *Vertex tool*. As soon as one of the latter tools are switched on the measured line disappears along with the measure window. In some cases however it is necessary to place a point or a line in a certain distance off another object. Therefore it would be handy to see the measured line while editing. Is there a workaround maybe or an alternative to the standard Measure Line tool or maybe any configuration which allows the Measure Line tool to stay open during editing?

Comment: I didn't believe you until I tested it.  It wasn't like that in QGIS 2 was it?  I seem to remember the lines remained visible until you closed the Measure window.

Answer (score 4):

When creating line objects the Advanced Digitizing window shows you distance (d), angle (a), x coordinate and y coordinate.

To use it, switch on both the Advanced Digitizing panel and toolbar and click the icon for 'Enable advanced digitizing tools' when you are editing

[image]

Comment: Interesting Panel which I haven't used before. To make it a useful alternative to the measure line tool, can I configure the advanced digitizing to:

- Angle indicator to have zero mark in North direction (not horizontal)
- Distance given in Nautical Miles
- snapping to common angles less than 5°